# firefox window in always on top mode

Tags: firefox, 22.04

[image]

For other apps I can do it, but for Firefox and chrome this option is not available.
I am using Ubuntu 22.04.
what is the problem with Browsers. I want to keep the browser on top of other windows, is there any workaround for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Try restoring the window down (the icon that looks like two overlapping squares next to the "Close" button). Ubuntu won't let you float a window if it is maximized.

<s>By default, the keyboard shortcut Alt+Space brings up the drop-down menu that includes "Always on Top."</s>

Source: https://www.maketecheasier.com/keyboard-shortcut-for-always-on-top-ubuntu/

Comment: thanks for taking your time and answering but I already know how to bring that menu, as you can see in the screenshot. Have you read the question properly?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Try restoring the window down (the icon that looks like two overlapping squares next to the "Close" button). Ubuntu won't let you float a window if it is maximized.

Comment: Ha, thanks for clarifying. That Alt+Space trick is doing it for me in Ubuntu 22.10. 
That strike-through is a joke, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is an  ad-on extension for `Firefox` which will do that for you... `Always on Top`

[image]

In `Firefox` go to the hamburger menu (3 parallel lines icon top right) and select `Add-ons and themes` or press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+A</kbd> and in the search box enter [image]

Comment: Thanks for this, but why in-built feature is not available for browsers. btw shortcut is  <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+A</kbd>

Comment: I've changed the shortcut to `Ctrl+Shift+A` in the answer. Thanks for that...